# Problem with Materialize chips-autocomplete

Tags: materialize

I have been trying to get chips autocomplete to work as part of a project.

I have stripped code right back to remove any odd effects and replicated code as on the Materialize site. As in attached code I can get autocomplete to work as expected but not with chips.

I have tried with Chrome and Edge browsers and various combinations of tags and class names but still unable to make it work.

So now I need some help!

What have I missed?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" >
<!-- autocomplete from materialize web site -->
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12">
            <div class="input-field col s6">
              <i class="material-icons prefix">textsms</i>
              <input type="text" id="autocomplete-input" class="autocomplete">
              <label for="autocomplete-input">from materialize web site</label>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  
  
<!-- chip autocomplete from materialize web site -->  
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s6">
            <div id="chips-autocomplete" class="chips chips-autocomplete " ></div>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>  <!-- container end -->

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script>        
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
                options={"data": {"abel":null,"baker":null,"charlie":null},
                         "placeholder":'fred'}
        console.log (options) 
        var autoElems = document.querySelectorAll('.autocomplete');
        var attemptElems = document.getElementById("attempt");
        var chipsElems = document.getElementById("chips-autocomplete");

        var auto = M.Autocomplete.init(autoElems, options);
        var chips = M.Chips.init(chipsElems, options);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data init for chips-autocomplete is incorrect. From the [docs](https://materializecss.com/chips.html#options):

```
  $('.chips-autocomplete').chips({
    autocompleteOptions: {
      data: {
        'Apple': null,
        'Microsoft': null,
        'Google': null
      },
      limit: Infinity,
      minLength: 1
    }
  });
```

With Vanilla JS:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.chips-autocomplete');
    var instances = M.Chips.init(elems, {
        autocompleteOptions: {
          data: {
            'Apple': null,
            'Microsoft': null,
            'Google': null
          },
          limit: Infinity,
          minLength: 1
        }
      });
  });
```

you are simply setting `data` (in quotes, when there should be no quotes). It should be `autocompleteOptions` as an object, and then `data` inside this.

Comment: Thanks Sean grateful for reply , yes i noted the example in the docs but I don't understand jQuery and had to guess at js version!    * Removing quotes around data has no effect    * Don't see point in renaming 'options' to 'autocompleteOptions as its just a name that is the second parameter in the 'init' call  * Placeholder object works  * options works with autocomplete.  Thanks Any ideas using plain js? (Apols for formatting haven't got hang of it yet)

Comment: My advice is to stick to the conventions in the documentation until you're familiar enough with the framework to freestyle. If you look inside the `chips` component, on line 8 it is looking for a variable called `autocompleteOptions`. So renaming this to options will infact break the component. I'll update my answer with the vanilla JS init but it is identical in structure.

Comment: Not clever enough to attempt freestyle! Unless you can understand JQuery the documentation is not clear. This works for me . . . options={autocompleteOptions: { data: { 'Abel': null, 'Baker': null,'Charlie': null },limit: Infinity, minLength: 1}};
var instances = M.Chips.init(chipsElems,options ); Thanks for your help Sean

Comment: No problem. Agreed the docs are bad - there are plans to improve being worked on currently. You can always drop in on the Gitter channel for advice https://gitter.im/Dogfalo/materialize